# What are the important (most common) features of Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am working on reading up on Silverlight 4 and wanted to know what are the most commonly used functions of Silverlight (so I can put a stronger emphasis on them) as opposed to features that are rarely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Five-Silverlight-4.0-features-you-cannot-do-without.aspx) you can find five great features of silverlight 4.0.

Short preview:

1. Webcam and Microphone
2. WebBrowser & HTMLBrush
3. Full Trust in Out of browser
4. Printing
5. RichText edit